# Why are some initialisms sometimes spelled with a slash? E.g. O/S for Operating System

Tags: terminology, abbreviations, acronyms, initialisms

I've only ever seen this practice used to refer to "Operating System" with "O/S", but [according to The Free Dictionary](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/O%2FS) there are a few more. Why is the slash in the middle sometimes used? Isn't "OS" or "O.S." more appropriate?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Depending on the style in use, in fact, *OS* or *O.S.* may be preferred to *O/S*. The slash is an older convention and more common in British usage than American, and helps distinguish that the two  or three letters it separates are an abbreviation rather than a short word or personal initials. See *[Why is there a slash within "n/a"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/12528)* and *[Where does A/C abbreviation for aircraft come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/144769/)*, as well as *[Using slash (/) as an abbreviation](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/396329)*.

Comment: Thank you for linking to the question about n/a choster. I searched for a similar question but couldn't find anything.