# What is the origin of shorthand for "with" -> "w/"?

Tags: writing-style, abbreviations

In many places, I've seen "w/" written instead of "with". At least, I think that one replaces the other. I couldn't find anywhere what is the origin of "w/".

Is this something in regular usage in the English language?

Comment: **In many places** -- In which case, examples should not be hard to find. Please give at least two examples including the context and source.

Comment: Related: [Q115367](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115367/are-w-o-w-b-c-common-abbreviations-in-the-us)

Comment: And see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_%28punctuation%29#Abbreviation) and [this question on n/a](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12528/why-is-there-a-slash-within-n-a)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are "w/o", "w/", "b/c" common abbreviations in the US?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115367/are-w-o-w-b-c-common-abbreviations-in-the-us)

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- That's not a duplicate. This question is asking about origin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[CyberDefinitions](https://www.cyberdefinitions.com/definitions/W_forward_slash.html) gives a plausible explanation:

> Although its origin is contested, ***w/*** has been used at least *since the rise of the fast-food industry in the 1950s*. ***As a form of shorthand to save time when writing down food orders, waiters replaced the words "with" and "without" with the abbreviations w/ and w/o .***
>
> Since that time, the use of w/ as an abbreviation of "with" has become much more widely used.

[WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/W-Meaning) gives detailed examples, explaining that

> It appears over text, on social media, in handwritten notes, or even in casual communications at work like Slack messages.

[Prowritingaid](https://prowritingaid.com/with-without-abbreviation) takes it further and adds that this abbreviation can be found in more formal contexts:

> Many people will use ***w/*** when they are ***taking notes***, whether in school, in a meeting or conference, or somewhere else. Using shorthand like this makes note taking much faster.
>
> It’s also common to see the abbreviation ***w/*** in ***real estate or housing descriptions***. Many ***descriptions of properties for sale or rent*** have limited characters, so they use abbreviations: “house w/ 2-car garage.”
>
> You might see the abbreviation for with on ***official forms or tables of research data*** that have a limited number of characters. It’s also common in ***informal communication*** as well as ***quick business communications***.

As an interesting fact, the site adds that

> Note that the medical field does not use w/ as the abbreviation for with. Instead, they use a lowercase C with a line over it. This stems from the Latin word for with, “cum.”

Comment: Really interesting. I must say that I never came across w/o.

Comment: Matching Latin-based abbreviation for without is s with a line.

Comment: "lowercase C with a line over it, called an overstrike" Which is it? c with a line over it? Or an overstrike?

Comment: @RosieF Most sites describe it as [_with a line over it_](https://blog.prepscholar.com/c-with-a-line-over-it-medical-abbreviation#:~:text=The%20c%20is%20almost%20always,notes%20written%20by%20medical%20professionals). I don't know why the site I am quoting calls it overstrike, I will omit it.

Comment: @KWriter, interesting that you've never seen "w/o".  My *guess* (which is why I'm not writing an answer) is that *w/o* came first, and people decided to start using *w/* only later.  My reasoning is that while there are few other one-letter-slash abbreviations, two-letter abbreviations with a slash are fairly common - for example, N/A, A/C, I/O - and at least some of those (N/A if nothing else) is older than the 1950s.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, and know that I've seen n/a (not applicable) and it is the only one that I've ever used :) I don't know (without searching for it) what is a/c. I guess i/o is input/output.

Comment: @RosieF The lower-case c with a line above it: that's how I was taught to abbreviate 'with' in school for note-taking purposes.